# Google Charts Tooltip: Remove values, keep percentage

Tags: php, charts, google-visualization

I'm using Google Charts to create a pie chart. Everything works fine so far. I want to remove the values and keep the percentage on the tooltips when hovering over a slice of the pie.

I tried adding:

```
tooltip: {
        text: 'percentage'
    }
```

(as I got recommended to do when searching for answers here)
To my:

```
Var piechart_options = {
    title:'Portföljfördelning',
    is3D: true,
    width:600,
    height:400        
};
```

As:

```
Var piechart_options = {
    title:'Portföljfördelning',
    is3D: true,
    width:600,
    height:400
    tooltip: {
        text: 'percentage'
        }    
  };
```

Unfortunately without success. When I add this, the chart is not even drawn anymore. Any suggestions?

The full code:

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc(db_query("SELECT * FROM investments ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;"));

echo '<div style="display: none;">';
foreach($result as $key => $value) {
    echo '<p class="investment_type">'. $key .'</p>';
    echo '<p class="investment_amount">'. $value .'</p>';
}
echo '</div>'

?>
<script>
var type = document.getElementsByClassName("investment_type");
var amount = document.getElementsByClassName("investment_amount");
var investment_type = [];
var investment_amount = [];
for(var i = 0; i < type.length; i++) {
    investment_type[i] = '"' + type[i].innerText + '"' || '"' + type[i].textContent + '"';
    investment_amount[i] = amount[i].innerText || amount[i].textContent;
}

google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Investeringsområde');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Procent');

    var rows = [];
    for (var i = 2; i < investment_type.length; ++i) {
        rows[i-2] =[investment_type[i], parseInt(investment_amount[i])];
    }

    data.addRows(rows);
    var piechart_options = {
        title:'Portföljfördelning',
        is3D: true,
        width:600,
        height:400        
    };

    var piechart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_portfolio_division'));
    piechart.draw(data, piechart_options);
}
</script>

<div class="row">
    <div id="chart_portfolio_division" class="col-md-6"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

just a typo, missing a comma...

```
Var piechart_options = {
    title:'Portföljfördelning',
    is3D: true,
    width:600,
    height:400,  // <-- comma was missing
    tooltip: {
        text: 'percentage'
    }    
};
```

Comment: Wow... That's embarrassing :-) Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
pieSliceText: "none"
```

i am using google chart and working on same thing i added above line in options object it is working for me,